# How do we generate the loop $ba$ from the loops $a^2,b^2$ and $ab\ $?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, covering-spaces, free-groups

[image]

In the second diagram a $2$-sheeted connected covering of the figure eight has been described. The image of the fundamental group of the covering space has the generators $a^2, b^2$ and $ab$ as claimed. But according to me the set of generators should include $ba$ as well. Could it be somehow possible to obtain $ba$ from the set of given generators $a^2, b^2$ and $ab\ $?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for investing your valuable time on my question.

Comment: $b^2(ab)^{-1}a^2$

Comment: @EricWofsey$:$ I see! Is there any to general way to determine how many generators are there in the image? Thanks for your prompt reply.

Comment: It seems like this might be related to the Word Problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_problem_for_groups), which is undecidable.